# Vista utility to monitor wifi signal?

Tags: windows-vista, display, wireless-networking, signal

I'm looking for a utility that runs on Vista to monitor the different wifi access-points in the neighborhood.

Inssider is nice, but it doesn't seem to show which AP I'm connected to, and neither does it support connecting to another AP by double-clicking on an item in the list.

Does someone know of a similar utility that has those missing features?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WirelessMon will do this, but why do you want to connect to other AP's? Connecting to an AP that is not yours is illegal.

Comment: It's legal to connect to my ISP's access-points anywhere (per the contract, each modem shares part of its bandwidth for use by any customer.)

Comment: More than happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with the one built into Vista? If you show the system tray icon, you will be notified of available wireless connections, and the interface is very convenient/simple to use.

Comment: I'd like something more comprehensive that Vista's tray applet, eg. one showing signal strength and updated every minute or so.

Comment: Vista's feature *does* show signal strength. Not sure about the update frequency, however.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended by [Gizmo's freeware](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-wi-fi-network-finder-utility.htm):

> [NetStumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/) is a free packet sniffer
>   utility used to locate Wi-Fi networks.
>   It's one of the first tools of its
>   kind and arguably still the best. So
>   much so that it is the standard
>   product used by war-drivers in their
>   perpetual search for free bandwidth
>   via unsecured Wi-Fi networks as well
>   as road-warriors looking to connect
>   their laptops back to the office.

Comment: But does it still support new(er) WiFi cards? I remember it as kind of selective.

Comment: Yes, it looks a bit selective. Funny, normally Gizmo's has good recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but NetStumbler doesn't seem to run on Vista and support connection to 802.11n

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetStumbler

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector](http://www.xirrus.com/library/wifitools.php), which does:

- Searching for Wi-Fi networks
- Managing and troubleshooting Wi-Fi connections
- Verifying Wi-Fi coverage
- Locating Wi-Fi devices
- Detecting rogue APs
- Available as widgets for Windows Vista, XP, Apple Mac OS X, Desklet for Linux

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but forgot to say that I'd rather a regular application, not a Vista widget.

Comment: This IS a regular application, which is also available in widget format.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the **free** [Wireless Net View from nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_view.html) for ages now, works on XP, Vista, Windows 7 absolutely fine (works on my Win7 64 bit), and *needs no installation* you just run the exe file, so it's a great one to keep on your USB key of utilities